# Inverted text in MKAnnotationView callout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mkmapview

I'm using this code to create a simple MKAnnotationView callout in Swift.

```
    let local_parking = CustomAnnotation()
    local_parking.coordinate = parking.coordinate.coordinate
    local_parking.title = "Street name"
    local_parking.subtitle = "Click on the button to get there"
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(local_parking)
}
.
.
.
func mapView(mapView:MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation:MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotation? {
    ...
    let customAnnotation = annotation as! CustomAnnotation
    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

    let accessoryButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = accessoryButton

    return annotationView
}
```

I don't know why some of the callouts appear inverted and others are showing properly.

[image]

Comment: You're not actually showing any of the key code / info needed to answer the question.

Comment: I'm just showing the piece of code related to the annotation's declaration and AnnotationView creation. What other code do you need to solve this issue?

Comment: How is the view actually created, and how is your app localized?

Answer (score 0):

Set your view's `semanticContentAttribute` to `.ForceLeftToRight` to prevent reversal under systems whose language is written right-to-left.

Comment: Setting the following aspects did not fix the issue.

    annotationView!.semanticContentAttribute = .ForceRightToLeft